# read values and path of files from a config file in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Read a config files like below  I can able to store the values of “info “by using array( by using split and join functions) and able to check the total values of each and every array value however I strucked  at reading the files under each info value.

```
[abc]
Info=alerts,requestes
[alerts]
total=23
/home/value/date/readme.txt
/root/File1
/home/File2
/users/cord/File3
[requestes]
Total=87
C:\user\user1\file1
C:\user\user1\file2
C:\user\user1\file3
```

Do you have any idea on this? How can we achive this by using perl. 
My Expected Output like this 
    FILES of alerts
    /home/value/date/readme.txt
    /root/File1 /home/File2
    /users/cord/File3
    Files of requestes
    C:\user\user1\file1
    C:\user\user1\file2
    C:\user\user1\file3

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: output should be like this
FILES of alerts
/home/value/date/readme.txt
/root/File1
/home/File2
/users/cord/File3

files of requestes
C:\user\user1\file1
C:\user\user1\file2
C:\user\user1\file3

Comment: Have you tried http://search.cpan.org/~gcarls/Config-IniFiles/IniFiles.pm?

Comment: it look for parameter and value where as my case there is no parameter only values...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a module from CPAN to do this, but it may be helpful. I wrote up some code that will hopefully get you started on this.

There are tons of ways to do this, but one way is to just read in the file, and parse it into a hash while using regular expressions to determine which line has what data or contents in it.

```
#!/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $file = <<'EOD';
[abc]
Info=alerts,requests
[alerts]
total=23
/home/value/date/readme.txt
/root/File1
/home/File2
/users/cord/File3
[requests]
Total=87
C:\user\user1\file1
C:\user\user1\file2
C:\user\user1\file3
EOD

my %info_hash;

my @file_contents = split('\n', $file);


my $title = shift @file_contents;
$title =~ s/\[(.*)\]/$1/g;

print "Title: $title\n";
my $info_string = shift @file_contents;
$info_string =~ s/^.*?=//;
my @info = split(',', $info_string);

my $key;

for my $line (@file_contents) {

    chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /^\[(.*?)\]/ ) {
        $key = $1;
    } elsif ( $line =~ /^total=(.*)/i ){
        $info_hash{$key}{total} = $1;
    } else {
        push @{$info_hash{$key}{values}}, $line;
    }
}

for my $entry (keys %info_hash) {
    print "Total for $entry is " . $info_hash{$entry}{total} . "\n";
    print join(" ", @{$info_hash{$entry}{values}}) . "\n";
}
```

This program is parsing it into a hash of hashes. The structure looks like this:

```
%info_hash =
'alerts' =>
{
      'values' => [
                    '/home/value/date/readme.txt',
                    '/root/File1',
                    '/home/File2',
                    '/users/cord/File3'
                  ],
      'total' => '23'
};
'requests' =>
{
      'values' => [
                    'C:\\user\\user1\\file1',
                    'C:\\user\\user1\\file2',
                    'C:\\user\\user1\\file3'
                  ],
      'total' => '87'
};
```

Let me know if you have any questions on how the code works. It may not be exactly what you want, but it's a starting point with an example on how you could store the data.

Comment: thanks, here i could not able to get the number of files i.e. values of Values how can i get that..

Comment: For the total number use `$info_hash{$entry}{total}` and for an array that stores all of the file names use `@{$info_hash{$entry}{values}}`. Check out the last for loop where they are printed for an example of how to get them. Hope this helps!

Comment: This code is complex enough to warrant looking on CPAN for a more supportable version